How can I get my Bitcoin account back?
I bought Bitcoins in 2009 or 2010 from a finance broker who posted his adv online with his name and contact info. he said that he could help people invest in Bitcoin with just just $2 to start, I contacted him and he sent me a link or site (I can't remember it anymore) to register an account, after I had done the account register and sent him money ( just $2) in 2009 or 2010 ?, however, I completely forgot about it over years until today. I completely forgot my log in details ( user name, password ), the email address which I used to register has been inactive and no long to get recovery anymore due to the platform stopped its services and no long exist anymore 10 years ago, and the platform have deleted data permanently, I also have lost the broker's contact info as well as I have changed my phone number years ago, then I tried to check the bank transaction but it isn't available because the transaction has been done over 7 years passed for recording period time. Now I have no any idea what I can do to get my Bitcoins back I lost all info, and I can't remember where I registered so I am unable get their customer service support ! Please give my any ideas that what I can do to get my Bitcoin account back ? Thank you.
